# Inconsistency between Spamassassin command line check vs daemon check

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

I'm running a mail server with postfix and spamassassin, and I appear to be getting a fair amount of junk mail through.

I picked on one email at random to compare what the email headers say regarding spamassassin and what a command line test on the same mail produces.

The results are not consistent:

Here are the relevant mail headers:

```
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on smtp.xxxxx.xxxx
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-0.9 required=1.5 tests=BAYES_00,DKIM_SIGNED,
    DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,HTML_IMAGE_RATIO_06,HTML_MESSAGE,MIME_HTML_ONLY,
    RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE,SPF_HELO_PASS,SPF_PASS,URIBL_GREY autolearn=no
    autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
```

Here is me checking the same mail on the command line: (Mails are stored on the filesystem via Maildir)

```
spamassassin -d -t < 1556039170.M973634P30465.smtp.xxxxx.xxxx\,S\=41505\,W\=42059\:2\,S
```

Here's the result:

```
Content analysis details:   (2.1 points, 1.5 required)
-0.0 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE     RBL: Sender listed at https://www.dnswl.org/, no
                            trust
                            [83.138.173.9 listed in list.dnswl.org]
 1.1 URIBL_GREY             Contains an URL listed in the URIBL greylist
                            [URIs: pure360.com]
-0.0 SPF_HELO_PASS          SPF: HELO matches SPF record
-0.0 SPF_PASS               SPF: sender matches SPF record
 0.0 HTML_IMAGE_RATIO_06    BODY: HTML has a low ratio of text to image area
 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
 1.1 MIME_HTML_ONLY         BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
-0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
                            domain
-0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid
```

This email should have been blocked by Spamassassin with a score of 2.1. However the mail header shows a score of -0.9. I observed the same issue with several other mails.

I don't understand this inconsistency? The only thing I noticed was a lag of maybe 3 seconds or so in the command line test before getting the result. Timeout issue maybe?

Comment: AFAIR spamassin has two modes of operation, in which one of them does not cut emails...cant be more specific right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your spamassassin deployed via postfix seems to use bad trained Bayes database.
see [BAYES_00](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/BAYES_00) test hit.

[BAYES_00](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/BAYES_00) should indicated low spam probability (below 1%).
It has **negative** score - (-1.9 when both network and bayes are used - see `50_scores.cf` file)

**Possible fix:**
remove Bayes databases/files and train Bayes database again.